# Why read system call stops reading when less than block is missing?

Tags: c++, posix, ipc, system-calls

### Introduction and general objective

I am trying to send an image from a child process (generated by calling `popen` from the parent) to the parent process.

The image is a grayscale `png` image. It is opened with the OpenCV library and encoded using `imencode` function of the same library. So the resulting encoded data is stored into a `std::vector` structure of type `uchar`, namely the `buf` vector in the code below.

### No error in sending preliminary image information

First the child sends the following image information needed by the parent:

- size of the `buf` vector containing the encoded data: this piece of information is needed so that the parent will allocate a buffer of the same size where to write the image information that it will receive from the child. Allocation is performed as follows (`buf` in this case is the array used to received data not the vector containing the encoded data):

  ```
   u_char *buf = (u_char*)malloc(val*sizeof(u_char));
  ```
- number of rows of the original image: needed by the parent to decode the image after all data have been received;
- number of columns of the original image: needed by the parent to decode the image after all data have been received.

These data are written by the child on the standard output using `cout` and read by the parent using `fgets` system call.

This pieces of information are correctly sent and received so **no problem until now**.

### Sending image data

The child writes the encoded data (i.e. the data contained in the vector `buf`) to the standard output using `write` system call while the parent uses the file-descriptor returned by `popen` to read the data. Data is read using `read` system call.

Data writing and reading is performed in blocks of `4096` bytes inside while loops. The writing line is the following:

```
written += write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf.data()+written, s);
```

where `STDOUT_FILENO` tells to write on standard output.
`buf.data()` returns the pointer to the first element in the array used internally by the vector structure.
`written` stores the number of bytes that have been written until now and it is used as index. `s` is the number of bytes (`4096`) that `write` will try to send each time.
`write` returns the number of bytes that actually have been written and this is used to update `written`.

Data reading is very similar and it is performed by the following line:

```
bytes_read = read(fileno(fp), buf+total_bytes, bytes2Copy);
```

`fileno(fp)` is telling from where to read data (`fp` is the filedescriptor returned by `popen`). `buf` is the array where received data is stored and `total_bytes` are the number of bytes read until now so it is used as index. `bytes2Copy` is the number of bytes expected to be received: it is wither `BUFLEN` (i.e. `4096`) or for the last block of data the remaining data (if for example the total bytes are `5000` then after 1 block of `4096` bytes another block of `5000-4096` is expected).

### The code

Consider this example. The following is a process launching a child process with `popen`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>//read
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#define BUFLEN 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //file descriptor to the child process
    FILE *fp;
    cv::Mat frame;
    char temp[10];
    size_t bytes_read_tihs_loop = 0;
    size_t total_bytes_read = 0;
    //launch the child process with popen
    if ((fp = popen("/path/to/child", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        //error
        return 1;
    }

    //read the number of btyes of encoded image data
    fgets(temp, 10, fp);
    //convert the string to int
    size_t bytesToRead = atoi((char*)temp);

    //allocate memory where to store encoded iamge data that will be received
    u_char *buf = (u_char*)malloc(bytesToRead*sizeof(u_char));

    //some prints
    std::cout<<bytesToRead<<std::endl;

    //initialize the number of bytes read to 0
    bytes_read_tihs_loop=0;
    int bytes2Copy;
    printf ("bytesToRead: %ld\n",bytesToRead);
    bytes2Copy = BUFLEN;
    while(total_bytes_read<bytesToRead &&
        (bytes_read_tihs_loop = read(fileno(fp), buf+total_bytes_read, bytes2Copy))
    )
    {
        //bytes to be read at this iteration: either 4096 or the remaining (bytesToRead-total)
        bytes2Copy = BUFLEN < (bytesToRead-total_bytes_read) ? BUFLEN : (bytesToRead-total_bytes_read);
        printf("%d btytes to copy\n", bytes2Copy);
        //read the bytes
        printf("%ld bytes read\n", bytes_read_tihs_loop);

        //update the number of bytes read
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read_tihs_loop;
        printf("%lu total bytes read\n\n", total_bytes_read);
    }
    printf("%lu bytes received over %lu expected\n", total_bytes_read, bytesToRead);
    printf("%lu final bytes read\n", total_bytes_read);
    pclose(fp);
    cv::namedWindow( "win", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    frame  = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1,total_bytes_read,0, buf), 0);
    cv::imshow("win", frame);

    return 0;

}
```

and the process opened by the above corresponds to the following:

```
#include <unistd.h> //STDOUT_FILENO
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define BUFLEN 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;
    //read image as grayscale
    frame = imread("test.png",0);
    //encode image and put data into the vector buf
    imencode(".png",frame, buf);
    //send the total size of vector to parent
    cout<<buf.size()<<endl;
    unsigned int written= 0;

    int i = 0;
    size_t toWrite = 0;
    //send until all bytes have been sent
    while (written<buf.size())
    {
        //send the current block of data
        toWrite = BUFLEN < (buf.size()-written) ? BUFLEN : (buf.size()-written);
        written += write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf.data()+written, toWrite);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

### The error

The child reads an image, encodes it and sends first the dimensions (size, #rows, #cols) to the parent and then the encoded image data.

The parent reads first the dimensions (no prob with that), then it starts reading data. Data is read `4096` bytes at each iteration. However when less than `4096` bytes are missing, it tries to read only the missing bytes: in my case the last step should read `1027` bytes (`115715%4096`), but instead of reading all of them it just reads `15.

What I got printed for the last two iterations is:

```
4096 btytes to copy
1034 bytes read
111626 total bytes read

111626 bytes received over 115715 expected
111626 final bytes read
OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /path/window.cpp, line 356
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) /path/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why isn't `read` reading all the missing bytes?

I am working on this image:[image]

There might be errors also on how I am trying to decode back the image so any help there would be appreciated too.

**EDIT**

In my opinion as opposed to some suggestions the problem is not related to the presence of `\n` or `\r` or `\0`.

In fact when I print data received as integer with the following lines:

```
for (int ii=0; ii<val; ii++)
{
    std::cout<<(int)buf[ii]<< " ";
}
```

I see `0`, `10` and `13` values (the ASCII values of the above mentioned characters) in the middle of data so this makes me think it is not the  problem.

Comment: Short reads (and `write`s) are always a possibility. Your code should always handle getting fewer bytes than it asked for and then retry the `read` (or `write`) for the remaining ones (usually).

Comment: `#define __OPENCV__` That identifier is reserved for the implementation. By defining it, your program has undefined behviour. You should use another header guard. Why are you using a header guard outside of the header anyway? Does the header lack header guards? Is the header written by you?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: `while(blk<((val/4096)+1));` what on God's green earth does this condition mean? You should read until EOF or error is reached, or until total bytes read equal total bytes you planned to read, whichever comes first.

Comment: For the image I am trying to send, the resulting number of bytes is not a multiple of `4096` so to read all of them I have to read `number_of_total_bytes/4096` times plus one more time for the remaining bytes. If for example the bytes are `5000` I have to call `read` `5000/4096` times, which is one plus another time to read the remaining 904 bytes. I tried also the condition `bytes_read<val` but it does not change a thing.

Comment: This is an wonderful piece of logic that unfortunately doesn't work. You *want* to read 4096 bytes at a time maximum, but there is nothing in the world that can guarantee you *will* be reading 4096 bytes at a time. You try to read 100, 1000, or 1000000 bytes at a time, it doesn't matter one little bit. What matters is the return value of `read` **only**. So this nice round 4096 value has absolutely no bearing on how many iterations you will actually need.

Comment: But the problem is that the child process sends all the data. The parent however is NEVER (it is not something random or occasionally) receiving the last missing block.

Comment: I'm not talking about that error. This will come in due course.`while (total_bytes_read < bytes_to_read && (bytes_read_this_time = read (...)) > 0) { total_bytes_read  += bytes_read_this_time; ... }` is bog-standard, transparent, understandable by everyone, absolutely foolproof way to read files, independent on buffer size or anything else, that can be demonstrated to actually do what's needed, has potential for error detection etc. What your code is doing, I have no idea and neither does anyone else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188630/discussion-between-n-m-and-francesco-boi).

Comment: The chat does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fgets(temp, 10, fp);
...
read(fileno(fp), ...)
```

This cannot possibly work.

`stdio` routines are **buffered**. Buffers are controlled by the implementation. `fgets(temp, 10, fp);` will read an unknown number of bytes from the file and put it in a buffer. These bytes will never be seen by low level file IO again.

You never, ever, use the same file with both styles of IO. Either do everything with `stdio`, or do everything with low-level IO. The first option is the easiest by far, you just replace `read` with `fread`.

If for some ungodly reason known only to the evil forces of darkness you want to keep both styles of IO, you can try that by calling `setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)` before doing anything else. I have never done that and cannot vouch for this method, but they say it should work. I don't see a single reason to use it though.

On a possibly unrelated, note, your reading loop has some logic in its termination condition that is not so easy to understand and could be invalid. The normal way to read a file looks approximately as follows:

```
 left = data_size;
 total = 0;
 while (left > 0 &&
        (got=read(file, buf+total, min(chunk_size, left))) > 0) {
    left -= got;
    total += got;
 }

 if (got == 0) ... // reached the end of file
 else if (got < 0) ... // encountered an error
```

---

The *more correct* way would be to try again if `got < 0 && errno == EINTR`, so the modified condition could look like

```
 while (left > 0 &&
        (((got=read(file, buf+total, min(chunk_size, left))) > 0) ||
        (got < 0 && errno == EINTR))) {
```

but at this point readability starts to suffer and you may want to split this in separate statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No evil forces at work here. I just need to read an integer which is used for allocation and `fgets` seemed the easiest way. I thought to use `read` but I do not know the number of digits (hence the byte since it is a string) to be read before. So you are suggesting to use `fread` instead of `read`? I used `read` because I am sure special characters are read anyway and do not interrupt the reading operation. Plus the problem of `fgets` reading an unknown number of bytes remains, doesn't it?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Yes, you should use fread. No, there will not be any additional problems or discrepancies or incompatibilities associated with it. Just write `fread` instead of `read` and shuffle the arguments appropriately. I know, I did that with your code. After the fix it worked as expected. I forgot to post the fixed code but the change is really trivial.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I'm not quite sure what "problem of fgets reading an unknown number of bytes" you are talking about. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You said "`fgets(temp, 10, fp);` will read an unknown number of bytes from the file and put it in a buffer. These bytes will never be seen by low level file IO again."

I was referring to this

Comment: @FrancescoBoi `read` is a low level IO routine. `fread` isn't. `fread` uses `FILE*`. The buffer sits in the `FILE*`. `fread` can see it jolly well. `read` has no idea about `FILE*` and its buffers.

Comment: Hi thanks I tested and your solution worked. There was also an error in my code though: I was calculating the umber of next bytes to be read before updating the total number of bytes that have been read until now. With this correction (should I correct the original question?) and your suggestion it worked.

Comment: Just more question: what if I want to use unbuffered I/O? Is there a direct equivalent for `fgets`?

Comment: No, you need to implement it yourself (by reading character by character until you see a newline).

Comment: Is it better to change the sending program to use buffered output (i.e. `fwrite` instead of `write`) as well? Or as opposed to buffered input might there be problems with special characters?

Comment: For the sending program it doesn't really matter. There's no problem of special characters.

Comment: hello again I changed the original program in the way the parent is sending img data to the child and child is supposed to show the image. This time I used only `fwrtite` to send and `fread` to read. However I am having the same problem so that the last bytes are not sent. I do not know if it's the case to ask another question: is it?

Comment: if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047561/buffered-read-write-of-image-data-between-parent-and-child-is-not-completing

Answer (score 0):

You're writing binary data to standard output, which is expecting text.  Newline characters (`\n`) and/or return characters (`\r`) can be added or removed depending on your systems encoding for end-of-line in text files.  Since you're missing characters, it appears that you system is removing one of those two characters.

You need to write your data to a file that you open in binary mode, and you should read in your file in binary.

Comment: that does not seem to be the problem: if I write `write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello\rworld\n", 13);` and read: `bytes_read = read(fileno(fp), (void*)(buf), 13);`, if I print the data as integer: `std::cout<<(int)buf[ii]<<" ";` then I see all data I have sent

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

I am not the world's best at C++, but this works and will give you a reasonable starting point.

`parent.cpp`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // File descriptor to the child process
    FILE *fp;

    // Launch the child process with popen
    if ((fp = popen("./child", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the number of bytes of encoded image data
    std::size_t filesize;
    fread(&filesize, sizeof(filesize), 1, fp);
    std::cout << "Filesize: " << filesize << std::endl;

    // Allocate memory to store encoded image data that will be received
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(filesize);

    int bufferoffset   = 0;
    int bytesremaining = filesize;
    while(bytesremaining>0)
    {
        std::cout << "Attempting to read: " << bytesremaining << std::endl;
        int bytesread   = fread(&buffer[bufferoffset],1,bytesremaining,fp);
        bufferoffset   += bytesread;
        bytesremaining -= bytesread;
        std::cout << "Bytesread/remaining: " << bytesread << "/" << bytesremaining << std::endl;
    }
    pclose(fp);

    // Display that image
    cv::Mat frame;
    frame = cv::imdecode(buffer, -CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    cv::imshow("win", frame);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

`child.cpp`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::FILE* fp = std::fopen("image.png", "rb");
    assert(fp);

    // Seek to end to get filesize
    std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    std::size_t filesize = std::ftell(fp);

    // Rewind to beginning, allocate buffer and slurp entire file
    std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(filesize);
    std::fread(buffer.data(), sizeof(uint8_t), buffer.size(), fp);
    std::fclose(fp);

    // Write filesize to stdout, followed by PNG image
    std::cout.write((const char*)&filesize,sizeof(filesize));
    std::cout.write((const char*)buffer.data(),filesize);
}
```

**Original Answer**

There are a couple of issues:

Your while loop writing the data from the child process is incorrect:

```
while (written<buf.size())
{
    //send the current block of data
    written += write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf.data()+written, s);
    i++;
}
```

Imagine your image is 4097 bytes. You will write 4096 bytes the first time through the loop and then try and write 4096 (i.e. `s`) bytes on the second pass when there's only 1 byte left in your buffer.

You should write whichever is the lesser of 4096 and bytes remaining in buffer.

---

There's no point sending the width and height of the file, they are already encoded in the PNG file you are sending.

There's no point calling `imread()` in the child to convert the PNG file from disk into a `cv::Mat` and then calling `imencode()` to convert it back into a PNG to send to the parent. Just `open()` and read the file as binary and send that - it is already a PNG file.

---

I think you need to be clear in your mind whether you are sending a PNG file or pure pixel data. A PNG file will have:

- PNG header,
- image width and height,
- date of creation,
- color type, bit-depth
- compressed, checksummed pixel data

A pixel-data only file will have:

- RGB, RGB, RGB, RGB

Comment: `Part1 of your answer ->` when I modified my question I thought about it too. I modified my code accordingly but still it is not working.

`Part2 of your answer ->` I did that because in some other posts they were using the number of rows and columns to decode the received image. That was a point I was not sure about so thanks. I am keeping `imread` for the moment  so that the same exact steps could be applied also to camera acquired images. 
 
`Part3 of your answer ->` Yes I have (even more now thanks for your comment)

Comment: Consider editing your question and putting in your latest, greatest code and ping me and I'll have another look.

Comment: I did edit my question with last changes and suggestions

Comment: I have updated my answer with some stuff that I call C++ that seems to work ok. You can improve it as you wish.