# buffered read/write of image data between parent and child is not completing

Tags: c++, ipc, fread

### Introduction and general objective

This question originated from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54656017/1714692) where I was trying to send image data from the child to the parent. The problem in that case was using buffered and unbuffered read functions. You can find working code of the old question at the bottom of this one.

Now I am trying to send an image from a parent process to the child process (generated by calling `popen` from the parent) that is supposed to show the iamge.

The image is a grayscale `png` image. It is opened with the OpenCV library and encoded using `imencode` function of the same library. So the resulting encoded data is stored into a `std::vector` structure of type `uchar`, namely the `img` vector in the code below.

### No error in sending some data

The size of the image is hard coded in child in the variable `img_size` for simplicity). This is used to allocate the memory where received data is stored. The allocation is the following:

```
    u_char *buf = (u_char*)malloc(img_size*sizeof(u_char));
```

### Sending image data

The parent writes the encoded data (i.e. the data contained in the vector `img`) to the `FILE*` stream returned by `popen` using `fwrite` while the child reads the data with `fread` using as `FILE*` the result of the conversion of the `STDIN_FILENO` file descriptor:

```
FILE * fp = fdopen(STDIN_FILENO, "r");
```

Data writing is performed in blocks `4096` bytes inside while loop while data reading reads in two calls of `fread` (I know it's ugly but this will be changed).

The writing loop is the following:

```
while (written<img.size())
{
    //bytes to send: 4096 or the remaining ones if less than 4096
    toWrite = BUFLEN < (img.size()-written) ? BUFLEN : (img.size()-written);
    //total bytes that have been sent until now
    written += toWrite*fwrite ( img.data()+written, toWrite, 1, f );
    printf("written: %ld\n", written);
 }
```

`img.data()` returns the pointer to the first element in the array used internally by the vector structure. 
`written` stores the number of bytes that have been written until now and it is used as index. 
`fwrite` returns the number of blocks (of size `toWrite` bytes each) that actually have been written and this is used to update `written`.

Data reading is very similar and it is performed by the following line (`bytes2Copy` is initialized to `4096`):

```
//read all possible bytes in blocks of 4096 until less than 4096 bytes remain
elRead = fread ( buf, bytes2Copy, img_size/bytes2Copy, fp);
total_bytes_read += elRead*bytes2Copy;
bytes2Copy = img_size-total_bytes_read; //now less than 4096 bytes remain
printf("child received %ld\n", total_bytes_read);
//read remaining bytes
elRead = fread ( buf+total_bytes_read, bytes2Copy, 1, fp);
```

`buf` is the array where received data is stored. `bytes2Copy` is either `BUFLEN` (i.e. `4096`) or for the last block of data the remaining data (if for example the total bytes are `5000` then after 1 block of `4096` bytes another block of `5000-4096` is expected).

### The code

Consider this example. The following is a process launching a child process with `popen`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>//read
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#define BUFLEN 4096

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    Mat frame;
    std::vector<uchar> img;
    //read image as grayscale
    frame = imread("/home/path/img/test.png",0);
    //encode image and put data into the vector buf
    imencode(".png",frame, img);
    //send the total size of vector to parent

    size_t toWrite = 0;
    size_t written= 0;
    FILE * f = popen("/home/path/childProcess", "w");
    printf("forked\n");
    while (written<img.size())
    {
        //send the current block of data
        toWrite = BUFLEN < (img.size()-written) ? BUFLEN : (img.size()-written);
        //written += write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf.data()+written, toWrite);
        written += toWrite*fwrite ( img.data()+written, toWrite, 1, f );
        printf("written: %ld\n", written);
    }
    wait(&status);
    return 0;

}
```

and the process opened by the above corresponds to the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define BUFLEN 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    size_t img_size = 115715;
    u_char *buf = (u_char*)malloc(img_size*sizeof(u_char));
    size_t total_bytes_read = 0;
    size_t elRead =0;
    size_t bytes2Copy = BUFLEN;
    FILE * fp = fdopen(STDIN_FILENO, "r");


    elRead = fread ( buf, bytes2Copy, img_size/bytes2Copy, fp);
    total_bytes_read += elRead*bytes2Copy;
    bytes2Copy = img_size-total_bytes_read;
    printf("child received %ld\n", total_bytes_read);
    elRead = fread ( buf+total_bytes_read, bytes2Copy, 1, fp); //sostituire 1
    total_bytes_read += elRead*bytes2Copy;//bytes_read_tihs_loop;
    printf("child received %ld\n", total_bytes_read);

    cv::namedWindow( "win", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    frame  = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1,total_bytes_read,0, buf), 0);
    cv::imshow("win", frame);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

### The error

The parent reads an image, encodes it and sends the encoded image data.

The child reads data in blocks of `4096`. However in the second call to `fread()` where less than `4096` bytes are missing, it tries to read only the missing bytes: in my case the second call to `frad` should read `1027` bytes (`115715%4096`). In this second call it is not reading anything although the parent sends (or at least seems to send) all the data.

Why isn't `fread()` reading all the missing bytes?

I am working on this image:[image]

There might be errors also on how I am trying to decode back the image so any help there would be appreciated too.

---

### Working code for the old question

Note that after the answer of the original question I managed to send data properly but from the child to the parent (in the other direction). The **working** code for this is the following:

Parent:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>//read
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define BUFLEN 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //file descriptor to the child process
    FILE *fp;
    cv::Mat frame;
    char temp[10] ={0};
    size_t bytes_read_tihs_loop = 0;
    size_t total_bytes_read = 0;
    unsigned short int elRead =0;
    size_t bytes2Copy = BUFLEN;
    //launch the child process with popen
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();
    if ((fp = popen("/home/path/childProcess", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        //error
        return 1;
    }

    //read the number of btyes of encoded image data
    fgets(temp, 10, fp);
    //convert the string to int
    size_t bytesToRead = atoi((char*)temp);
    //some prints
    std::cout<<bytesToRead<<std::endl;

    //allocate memory where to store encoded iamge data that will be received
    u_char *buf = (u_char*)malloc(bytesToRead*sizeof(u_char));

    //initialize the number of bytes read to 0
    printf ("bytesToRead: %ld\n",bytesToRead);
    elRead = fread ( buf+total_bytes_read, bytes2Copy, bytesToRead/bytes2Copy, fp);
    total_bytes_read += elRead*bytes2Copy;
    bytes2Copy = bytesToRead-total_bytes_read;
    elRead = fread ( buf+total_bytes_read, bytes2Copy, bytesToRead/bytes2Copy, fp);
    total_bytes_read += elRead*bytes2Copy;
    printf("%lu bytes received over %lu expected\n", total_bytes_read, bytesToRead);
    printf("%lu final bytes read\n", total_bytes_read);
    pclose(fp);
    cv::namedWindow( "win", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    frame  = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1,total_bytes_read,0, buf), 0);
    cv::imshow("win", frame);
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time with %d buffer length: %f\n", BUFLEN, cpu_time_used);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

Child:

```
#include <unistd.h> //STDOUT_FILENO
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define BUFLEN 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    std::vector<uchar> buf;
    //read image as grayscale
    frame = imread("/home/path/test.png",0);
    //encode image and put data into the vector buf
    imencode(".png",frame, buf);
    //send the total size of vector to parent
    cout<<buf.size()<<endl;
    unsigned int written= 0;

    int i = 0;
    size_t toWrite = 0;
    //send until all bytes have been sent
    FILE * f = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");
    while (written<buf.size())
    {
        //send the current block of data
        toWrite = BUFLEN < (buf.size()-written) ? BUFLEN : (buf.size()-written);
        //written += write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf.data()+written, toWrite);
        written += toWrite*fwrite ( buf.data()+written, toWrite, 1, f );
        i++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Although I haven't identified your specific issue, I suggest having the child process specify 1-byte element size to `fread()`, and the expected number of bytes to read as the number of elements.  Since you know how many bytes to expect, you should be able to use a single `fread()` call for this.  Similarly, I would use a single `fwrite()` rather than manually breaking the output into blocks.

Comment: That's nn it the issue: I tried different parameters the code at the bottom of my question for the previous question works while the other does not.