# Sending buffer in c socket programming with write

Tags: c, sockets, posix, system-calls

I'm creating a TCP chat room in C with `fork()`. Every client message should reach server with username and message in buffer, so I use `strcpy(buffer, name)` and `strcat(buffer, ": ")` to combine buffer and name. After that I use

```
n = write (sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer))
```

to send buffer to server. So right here strange thing happens, my server show nothing, but after that when I use

```
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

string is correctly transferred. Here is my server code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    int port;
    int i = 1;
    printf("Enter port ->");
    scanf("%d", &port);

    int sockfd, newsockfd, n;
    char buffer[255];
    struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int ret, flag;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if (sockfd < 0){
        printf("Error opening socket\n");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    flag = 1;
    ret = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    if (ret < 0){
        printf("Set sock opt errror\n");
    }
    serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serv_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        printf("Error binding\n");
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    int pid;

    while(1){
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0){
            printf("Error on accept\n");
        }
        printf("New connection\n");
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0){
            printf("Error on pid\n");
        }
        if (pid == 0){
            close(sockfd);
            while(1){
                bzero(buffer, 255);
                n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
                if (n < 0){
                    printf("Error on reading\n");
                }
                printf("%s", buffer);
                n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                if (n < 0){
                    printf("Error on writing\n");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

and client code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    int port;
    printf("Enter port ->");
    scanf("%d", &port);
    char ip[10];
    printf("Enter ip -> ");
    scanf("%s", &ip);
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name -> ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    int sockfd, n;
    char buffer[255];
    struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if (sockfd < 0){
        printf("Error opening socket\n");
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "ip", &serv_addr.sin6_addr);
    serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        printf("Connection failed\n");
    }

    while(1){

        bzero(buffer, 255);
        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
        strcpy(buffer, name);
        strcat(buffer, ": ");
        n = write (sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        bzero(buffer,255);
        if (n < 0){
            printf("Error on writing\n");
        }
        n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
        printf("%s", buffer);
        if (n < 0){
            printf("Error on reading\n");
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);
}
```

So maybe someone can see the problem why client can't send full buffer with name and message to server? I think the problem is something with `name`. When I send only the buffer that I get using

```
fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
```

server works fine, but I need client username.

I tried to test `strlen(name)` and `buffer` and everything seems okay. What I tried to do is manually convert name to buffer like this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++){
        buffer[i] = name[i];
 }
```

But then if it's the only way to do this, how should I push the buffer to the right entering name and don't lose message information?

Comment: I don't quite get how this should work. You read a message into the buffer: `fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);` and then directly overwrite it, discarding the previous string: `strcpy(buffer, name);`. Why?

Comment: The question is very unclear. How many clients do you have? Who is sending? Who is receiving? The server is receving or just not printing?  *but after that when I use  `n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255); printf("%s", buffer);` information is perfectly fine* who is calling those lines? *why client can't send full buffer with name and message to server*? wasn't information fine? *When I send only the buffer that I get using fgets(buffer, 255, stdin)* `fgets` receive data, does not send any.

Comment: @Ctx `fgets` gets the message and then I try to combine it with the username.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi so let's say we have 1 client. He enters port, ip and name. Then he writes a message to buffer, and server should print out this message. Everything works fine if I send pure buffer, but after `strcpy` and `strcat` server don't print out anything, but client console prints out fine.

Comment: Is the client that sent the buffer that will print fine? If so this should be quite obvious I think. If you specify your inputs I will try it.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi yes, client that sends buffer prints out fine, but server don't and I can't see the obvious part. So port imput should be the same on both server and client, any number <1024, ip can be both v6 and v4 so you can enter 127.0.0.1 or ::1 and name can be yours.

Comment: Your string isn't even null-terminated so there is nothing fine with this code.

Comment: @SauliusMeidus You can check the answer. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has plenty of errors :).

First of all `scanf` takes as 1st argument a pointer, so when you want to use it for a string do:

```
char ip[10];
...
scanf("%s", ip);//THIS IS CORRECT
```

not `scanf("%s", &ip);`.

On the server the compiler was complaining about the type of `clilen`. `accept` is expecting a `sockelen_t` (or equivalently `unsigned int`) while you declared that variable as a simple `int`.

---

### Main problem

It is the following. In the client you did `strcpy(buffer, name);` which copies `name` starting from the beginning of the buffer but the beginning of the buffer actually contained your data. You should do something like the following using `strcat` as you did in the next line:

```
    bzero(buffer, 255);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
    strcat(buffer, name);
    strcat(buffer, ": ");
```

---

### Further general advice

Also note another thing: avoid mixing system call functions `read` `write` `getchar` with library functions such as `fread`, `fwrite`, `fgets`. I was having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54656017/1714692) with that causing by the fact that `fgets` might read more bytes than expected. In your case should be ok because you are using them for different purposes.